# format specifier value issue in c

Tags: c, format-specifiers

```
int friends = 20;

printf("I have %d friend%c", friends , (friends !=1 ? "s" : ""));

return 0;
```

So whenever I run the code it debugs into this

```
I have 20 friend$
```

It works fine when I run it with %s format specifier after the `friend`. `s` is only one character so why doesn't it work?

Comment: `"s"` isn't a char, neither is `""`. Try `%s`.

Comment: In C, strings are enclosed in double quotes (`"`) and characters are in single quotes (`'`). So you can as tkausl says use `%s` instead of `%c`, or use `'s'` and `' '` (a single space) instead of `"s"` and `""`, repectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*so why doesn't it work?* because `%c` expects `char` but expression `(friends !=1 ? "s" : "")` results in strings(double quotes). So either use `%s` like

```
printf("I have %d friend%s", friends , (friends !=1 ? "s" : ""));
```

Or

Replace `"s"` with `'s'` and `""` with `' '` as `%c` expects `char`.

```
printf("I have %d friend%c", friends , (friends !=1 ? 's' : ' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

**"s" is not a one character, its a String Literal whose type is char ***
**'s' is one character Constant whose type is int.**
String Literal in C requires double quotes, and printf( ) have format specifier %s to print string literals.
Character Constant in C requires single quotes, and printf( ) have format specifier %c to print them.

Now your code snippet,

```
printf("I have %d friend%c", friends , (friends != 1 ? "s" : ""));
```

will return string literal, since

```
"s" or " "
```

is string literal and printf( ) requires format specifies "%s" to print them.

if you want to use %c format specifier in code snippet, then use, character constant 's' instead of string literal "s"

```
printf("I have %d friend%c", friends , (friends != 1 ? 's' : ' '));
                                                              ^
```

Also note that, there must be a space between single quotes as show above the caret symbol otherwise it would give **error: empty character constant.**
In case of string literals, empty string is allowed.